# How to balance containers on newly added node with same elastic IP?

Tags: docker, autoscaling, docker-swarm-mode

I need help in distributing already running containers on the newly added docker swarm worker node.

I am running docker swarm mode on docker version - 18.09.5. I am using AWS autoscaling for creating 3 masters and 4 workers. For high availability, if one of the workers goes down, all the containers from that worker node will be balanced on other workers. When autoscaling brings new node up, I am adding that worker node to the current docker swarm setup using some automation. But docker swarm is not balancing containers on that worker node. Even I tried to deploy the docker stack again, still swarm is not balancing the containers. Is it because of different node id? How can I customize it? I am using docker compose file deploying stack.

```
docker stack deploy -c dockerstack.yml NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

The only (current) to force re-balancing, is to force-update the services. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/admin_guide/#force-the-swarm-to-rebalance for more information.